# Check if a UIViewController was initialized before performing an unwindSegue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, unwind-segue

I have an application with a structure similar to this:

[image]

When I run the App for the first time it will go through the VCs like this:

```
LoadingVC > LoginVC > NavBarController_1 > VC1_1 > VC1_2 > NavBarController_2 > VC2_1 > VC2_2 > TabBarController_1 > NavBarController_3 > VC3_1_1
```

However, when it runs the app the second time it will go straight to `LoginVC > TabBarController_1 > NavBarController_3 > VC3_1_1`.

From here I want to be able to go VC1_1 and NavBarController_1 > VC1_1 and  NavBarController_2 > VC2_1 from within the hamburger menu.

My LoginVC looks like this:

```
if( CONDITION_1 == true )
{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginVCToNavBarController_1", sender: self)
}
else if( CONDITION_2 == true )
{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginVCToNavBarController_2", sender: self)
}
else
{
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginVCToTabBarController_1", sender: self)
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    print("LoginVC > prepareForSegue")

    if(segue.identifier == "loginVCToNavBarController_1")
    {
        _ = (segue.destination as! NavBarController_1)
    }
    else if(segue.identifier == "loginVCToNavBarController_2")
    {
        _ = (segue.destination as! LoginUserVC)
    }
    else if(segue.identifier == "loginVCToTabBarController_1")
    {
        _ = (segue.destination as! TabBarController_1)
    }
}
```

I am still trying to figure it out how unwindSegues work so here are my questions / problems:

I. When I am in the TabBarController_1, depending on how the app flow, VC1_1 and / or VC2_1 could have been initialized or not so I want to know when should I perform a normal segue and when to do a unwindSegue.

Please keep in mind that unwindSegue will not always be from one VC to another VC under the same Navigation Controller but mainly from one VC to the root of another NavBarController.

Right now I can think of 2 ways of doing this: check if a VC was initialized or not or if the segue is possible or not using shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier but I can't seem to find some examples (or maybe I am not searching for the right thing).

I did some digging and found shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier but I am not sure how I should use it.
According to Apple, shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier returns YES if the segue should be performed or NO if it should be ignored.

Unfortunately I can't seem find out how is the condition validated. Moreover, if I try `print(self.shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindFromSideMenuVCToLoginUserVC", sender: self))`, it always returns TRUE. In fact, it returns TRUE even if I use a segueIdentifier for a segue that does not really exist.

II. I already have an unwindSegue for the logout action but in this case I know the LoginVC is always there because I am forced to go through it.

```
@IBAction func unwindFromSideMenuVCToLoginUserVC(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) { }
```

However, in this case, if instead of closing the app, I login again, shoud I use normal segue or unwindSegue?
Or should I dismiss all controllers and go back to root:

```
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In this case it will take me to LoadingVC and then push the LoginVC.

Any thoughts / suggestions?

Comment: You return true or false from your implementation of `shouldPerformSegue` depending on whether you want the segue to go ahead or not.

Comment: You can examine the [`presentingViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller) property of your tab bar controller and check if it is the login view controller or not.

Comment: @Paulw11 - I know I can use shouldPerformSegue. The problem is it's not very clear to me HOW do I use it. I was unable to find any example so far. And Apple documentation does not help much either.

Comment: I am not sure that you do want to use `shouldPerformSegue`, but as I said, if you do, you need to write an override function that *returns true or false* depending on whether you want the segue to be performed. The default implementation simply returns `true`, which is why you always get `true` if you haven't provided an overidden function in your view controller.  I think you should be able to check the presenting view controller of your tab bar and then perform the appropriate segue.

Answer (score 0):

**UIViewController** has property called **isViewLoaded**, you can use it

For example

```
if vc.isViewLoaded {
 // perform segue
}
```

> **var isViewLoaded: Bool { get }**
>
> Description:
>   A Boolean value indicating whether the view is currently loaded into
>   memory. The value of this property is true when the view is in memory
>   or false when it is not. Accessing this property does not attempt to
>   load the view if it is not currently in memory.

Comment: Thanks. I did try it and I get "Instance member 'isViewLoaded' cannot be used on type 'DataNavControllerVC'"